# Open a file in VSCODE from keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am just testing VSCODE. I want to open a file from the keyboard. To my surprise it is a bit difficult. Try this:

1. **Ctrl-O** (Opens the file dialog. This puts cursor focus in the "File name" field.)
2. **Shift-Tab** (To try to go backwards to the list of files.)

At this point I am stuck. Cursor focus is now not in the list of files, but in the headings above it. If I try **Tab** I just get back to the "File name" field.

How do I go to the list of files with the keyboard?

UPDATE: This is on Windows 10.

UPDATE 2: Issued a bug report, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63260

Answer (score 0):

As step 2, can you try using up-arrow or down-arrow key directly without using tab. It works this way on my mac. you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work here on Windows 10. The down arrow opens a menu (which allows you to restrict the number of files shown). The up arrow does nothing AFACS.